# "input expected at most 1 arguments, got 2"

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a function that will prompt the user to give a radius for each circle that they have designated as having, however, I can't seem to figure out how to display it without running into the `TypeError: input expected at most 1 arguments, got 2`

```
def GetRadius():
    NUM_CIRCLES = eval(input("Enter the number of circles: "))
    for i in range(NUM_CIRCLES):
        Radius = eval(input("Enter the radius of circle #", i + 1))

GetRadius()
```

Comment: While `print(thing1, thing2)` prints `thing1` and `thing2` separated by a space, that's a feature of how `print` handles arguments, not a general way to stick multiple things together in any code that produces output. `input` takes at most a single argument to print, which must be a string.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you gave it a second argument.  You can only give it the string you want to see displayed.  This isn't a free-form **print** statement.  Try this:

```
Radius = eval(input("Enter the radius of circle #" + str(i + 1)))
```

This gives you a single string value to send to **input**.

Also, be *very* careful with using **eval**.

Answer (score 1):

`input` only takes one argument, if you want to create a string with your `i` value you can use

```
Radius = eval(input("Enter the radius of circle #{} ".format(i + 1)))
```

Also it is [*very dangerous* to use `eval` to blindly execute user input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/is-using-eval-in-python-a-bad-practice).

Answer (score 0):

> TypeError: input expected at most 1 arguments, got 2

Thats because you provided two arguments for input function but it expects one argument (yeah I rephrased error message...).

Anyway, use this:

```
Radius =  float(input("Enter the radius of circle #"  + str(i + 1)))
```

Don't use `eval` for this. (Other answer explains why)

For future issues, it's worth using `help` function from within python interpreter. Try `help(input)` in python interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

In `golang` I got the exact same error using database/sql when I tried this code:

```
    err := db.QueryRow("SELECT ... WHERE field=$1 ", field, field2).Scan(&count)
    if err != nil {
        return false, err
    }
```

it turns out the solution was to do add 1 parameter instead of 2 parameters to the varargs of the function.

so the solution was this:

```
    err := db.QueryRow("SELECT ... WHERE field=$1 ", field).Scan(&count)
    // notice field2 is missing here
    if err != nil {
        return false, err
    }
```

I hope this helps anyone, particularly since this is the first google result when googling this issue.

also guys, always provide context to your errors.

HTH