# user input for decision on list items

Tags: python, user-input

I want to write a program where the user decides whether or not two sentences are similar.

I already made some comparisons with word embeddings and cosine similarity.
Now, the user should look through the results of the cosine similarity and decide whether these sentences are really so similar like the automatic comparison suggests.

I cannot find any tool or library that is designed for this and standard `input` doesn't let me do what I want.

This is what I want to do:

```
potential_similars = [(sent1, sent2), (sent3, sent4), (sent5, sent6), (sent6, sent8)]
approved_simil = []
not_approved_simil = []
for tup in potential_similars:
  query = input("should " , tup[0], " and ", tup[1], " be regarded as similar? Type Y if yes and N otherwise")
  if query == "Y":
    approved_simil.append(tup)
  elif query == "N":
    not_approved_simil.append(tup)
```

Comment: And what's the _problem_ with what you've posted? I guess `TypeError: input expected at most 1 argument...`, in which case did you research that? Have you read e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/43243627/3001761?

Comment: `query = input(f"should {tup[0]} and {tup[1]}  be regarded as similar? Type Y if yes and N otherwise")`

Comment: "standard input doesn't let me do what I want." What exactly is it that you want `input` to do? What happens when you try to run the code, and how is that different from what you want to happen?

Comment: In your own words, when you write something like `input(x, y, z)`, what do you think the commas mean? What do you want them to mean? Is this perhaps based off of how you use them somewhere else, for example, when you call `print`?

Comment: thank you all, I didnt realize it was as simple as that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

input just wants one string. Join the strings together before passing them to the input:

```
query = input("".join(("should " , tup[0], " and ", tup[1], " be regarded as similar? Type Y if yes and N otherwise")))
```

Comment: thank you! I did it with string concatination (just using "+") but this is way more elegant